# Migrating from Intel CPU to AMD one

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, intel, cpu, amd-processor

My OS is currently Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

My current CPU is: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU

I'm going to upgrade my Motherboard, CPU, Memory, to AMD Family with an AMD Ryzen 9 5950x.

Will my OS seamlessly work after hardware upgrade, or do I need to perform some operation to upgrade my OS/Software to be able to work with my new Hardware?

Comment: If you are going to *drastically* change the foundational hardware of the system, it is *strongly* advised that you do a full installation from scratch. This will reduce the number of headaches you'll have afterwards.

Comment: If you ensure all packages are included, I've had cases where changing motherboards (*because of failures*) was easily done and without issue, yet other times it's been horrific (with replacement board from the same brand/model of box, same family processor & thus near identical specs; though a few components differed as is common).  In my own experience, you're *flipping a coin*.

Comment: Haha I like this expression ^^ Ok ... so there is no 'magic instructions' allowing to request a "OS migration according to Hardware migration" ? Including Grub boot options for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu should work with no problems. I did that many times. There is nothing specific with Intel or AMD CPUs that need attention.

The only issue that can arise is GPU driver. if you installed some 3rd-party driver like Nvidia and changed this hardware to something else, you need to uninstall the driver first.

The same applies to other drivers if you installed any manually.

If you don't have 3rd party drivers, the system should boot on another MB without any issues. Linux systems don't store hardware information on disk, like Windows.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your answer. I see at least (obviously) issue with an intel RAID 0 (I will manage it before); and maybe some Grub options; but I don't see anything else like you say.