# Ubuntu from AMD to Intel motherboard

Tags: boot, dependencies, intel, amd-processor

I'm changing some existing Ubuntu 18.04 install from AMD to Intel motherboard.

On booting with Intel mobo, it stopped to boot in the end with a complain that

> ***Timed out waiting for device dev-di...y\x2dduid-6E6274DB6274AA0B.dev...***

> ***Dependency failed for /mnt/6E6274DB6274AA0B.***

1. Is it possible to boot on Intel mb previous AMD mb installation?
2. How to fix this os install to run on the Intel motherboard?

There is a question similar, that states that it is possible in reverse case, Intel to AMD, and insist on removing GPU driver first before change.

[Migrating from Intel CPU to AMD one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307879/migrating-from-intel-cpu-to-amd-one)

My both installs on the motherboards are with NVidia GPUs, very similar.

3. Can I remove bad driver or whatever else or should I still try to remove some GPU driver?

Note.
There is somewhat looking as a file or folder

/mnt/6E6274DB6274AA0B

when drive in accessed from PE Win10.
Deleting it results in completely broken boot, so I have to restore it by check.

1. Is it possible to fix the install trying to reinstall from Live flash drive?

**UPDATE:**

I checked file /etc/fstab contents, and it is as follows:

```
*# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7d79a32e-4cae-4c47-9736-9ef5e96f15d9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6E6274DB6274AA0B /mnt/6E6274DB6274AA0B auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0*
```

So despite of ***nofail*** option, as it was advised, for example, in

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326791/cannot-boot-because-missing-external-disk

boot still fail.
Should I just remove the mounting point in this file, or do something else to get rid of the issue?

**UPDATE:**

I did comment last string

```
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/6E6274DB6274AA0B
```

and boot a bit continued, but stuck at

“Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes",

which is as far as I can see in questions may be a problem with repository update, graphical driver and other reasons.

So, how to troubleshoot and fix the issue?

May be, it's possible to fix the install trying to reinstall from Live flash drive?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the different hardware platform. The message is about a now nonexistent (or identified differently) partition in your fstab. Should be easy to correct but a fresh installation always gives better results.

Comment: @ChanganAuto

I would continue to use  this install.

 1. How to fix this problem on os boot?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to switch from a CPU brand to another, but that's not your problem.

If this device `6E6274DB6274AA0B` is not critical for you (or if you don't know what it is), I'd recommend your remove it from fstab (comment it out is the safe way).

I may be a device present in your old config that is not there anymore.

Once you regain access to the OS, you should be able to figure out if something is missing.

Comment: thanks, it's moved one step, but stuck again. May be you've ideas?

Comment: “Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"

That's a step forward in the right direction. To troubleshoot further, you should try to look at your `/var/log/boot.log` (or at least the latest log that was being fed, it should tell what went wrong)