# Transplanting 20.04 from Intel to AMD PC

Tags: intel, amd-processor

I have an Intel Dell Optiplex (Intel iGPU) outfitted with a 20.04 SSD and the goal is to transplant a disk to an AMD Laptop: Aspire V5-122p-0857.  There is anecdotal testimony that this is possible: [Migrating from Intel CPU to AMD](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307928/545291)

What, if any, procedure can / must be performed to assure a smooth transplant? Any lessons-learned are always appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated NVidia graphics card? Otherwise, just change the hard drive, and it should work just fine. I had a  portable Ubuntu installation in an USB stick, which worked flawlessly with 4 computers without any issues (all had different intel processors, but different models).

Comment: The kernel has build in drivers, and is supposed to recognize the hardware. Change the hard drive, and if you encounter any error, edit the question. Otherwise, this question really cannot be answered.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed in an USB drive. It works in both my AMD laptop and Intel NUC desktop. Neither computer has discrete graphics cards or WiFi cards that need special drivers.

Comment: By the way, all you can expect is anecdotal evidence. I don't see how you can get enough data to statistically test the hypothesis that Ubuntu originally installed on Intel CPU works on AMD CPU.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from Intel CPU to AMD one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307879/migrating-from-intel-cpu-to-amd-one)